# problem with 003 factory

Tags: pro-tools, recording, software, hardware

hi all am i have Macpro
One 2.8GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon "Nehalem" processor/3GB (three 1GB)memory System lion
and 003 Factory Complete The Ultimate Tactile Pro Tools LE
the Complete Production Toolkit running Avid Pro Tools 10 i have problem with 003 factory Fader don't move when checking the version on the device X.xx  and sometimes the 003 became offline and protool's open

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the updated drivers? They're actually separate from the software installer.

They can be found [here](http://avid.custkb.com/avid/app/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=379411), under the "Pro Tools Firewire Device Drivers" heading.